# Rails 3.2 rake compilation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, bundler

Suddenly can't push to Heroku! the error message says:

> uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass

(Same exact code and libraries that worked fine until 2 days ago!)

Compilation apparently failing on this line of application.rb:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

When compilation is attempted I get this:

> Could not detect rake tasks    ensure you can run `$ bundle exec
>   rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present    and
>   using the production group of your Gemfile.    This may be
>   intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run    cancel the build
>   (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:    rake aborted!
>   uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass

Full stack trace:

```
/tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/util.rb:348:in `try_sass'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/sass/rails3_shim.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/sass-3.3.2/lib/sass/root.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/sass-3.3.2/lib/sass/util.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/sass-3.3.2/lib/sass/version.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `try_sass'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/sass.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
    gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
    gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
    gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
    gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/config/application.rb:7:i
n `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/Rakefile:5:in `require'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/Rakefile:5:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
       /tmp/build_ae51e5ec-bc73-4105-bce5-33edbe8bee32/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'

   vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
-----> WARNINGS:
   Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
   Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
   Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
   Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
   Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
   This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
   In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> (none)
   Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
```

GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'useragent'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'vpim'
gem 'ri_cal'
gem "geocoder"
gem 'sass'
gem 'haml', '3.1.6'
gem 'settingslogic', '~> 2.0.8'
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'omniauth', '1.1.0'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.1'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem "omniauth-google", "~> 1.0.2"
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'aws-s3', '~> 0.6.3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6.9'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '0.4.4'
gem "fb_graph", '2.4.19'
gem "linkedin"
gem "twitter"
gem "nokogiri", "~> 1.5.5"
gem "gdata", :git=> "https://github.com/agentrock/gdata.git"
gem 'acts_as_api', "0.4.1"
gem "rails_admin"
gem "meta_search", "~> 1.1.3"
gem "possessive", "~> 1.0.1"
gem "rake", "10.0.3"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "json", "1.7.7"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem "google-api-client", :require => 'google/api_client'
gem "rest-client", "~> 1.6.7"
gem "customerio"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails','~> 0.3.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.0.0'
  gem "spork", "~> 0.9.2"
  gem 'hoe', '~> 3.4.0'
end

group :test do
  gem "shoulda",          ">=3.0.1"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', "1.4.0"
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
end
```

Comment: Please show us your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Edited to include gem file

Comment: Running into this issue this morning.

Answer (score 7):

You are using haml 3.1.6 which is breaks on this version of sass.

The best fix is to update to the newest version of haml 4.0.x:

```
$ bundle update haml haml-rails
```